# Spark Streaming tumbling window hourly intervals

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Quick question on Spark tumbling windows. Let's say I have some info on sales per shop:

```scala
val testShopStats = Seq(SalesStatsPerShop(1465430402000l, "2016-06-09 00:00:00", "2016-06-09 01:00:00", "NewYorker", 120.0, "Germany", "Munich"))
```

in the case above timestamp 1465430402000 corresponds to Thu Jun 09 2016 00:00:02

I'm trying to calculate average sales with different hour interval, like below:

```scala
val preAggregatedAverage =
  lines
    .withWatermark("timeStamp", "2 hours")
    .groupBy($"shop", $"country", $"city", window($"timeStamp", "2 hours"))
    .agg(avg($"amount") as "avgAmount")
```

I expect that each time I specify hourly window I do get window started from 00:00, however that doesn't always like that:

```
window = 1 hour
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|shop     |country|window                                    |
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|NewYorker|Germany|[2016-06-09 00:00:00, 2016-06-09 01:00:00]|
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+

window = 2 hours
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|shop     |country|window                                    |
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|NewYorker|Germany|[2016-06-08 23:00:00, 2016-06-09 01:00:00]|
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+

window = 4 hours
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|shop     |country|window                                    |
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|NewYorker|Germany|[2016-06-08 23:00:00, 2016-06-09 03:00:00]|
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+

window = 6 hours
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|shop     |country|window                                    |
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|NewYorker|Germany|[2016-06-08 21:00:00, 2016-06-09 03:00:00]|
+---------+-------+------------------------------------------+
```

Question is: how does that window start date is determined in case of hourly intervals?

Thanks